# Format a string as a serial number

Tags: php, regex

I'd like to format a string into a serial number. I'd like to get something like that:
`AAAAA-BBBBB-CCCCC-DDDDD` with alpha-numeric characters (`0-9ABCDEF`).

So far, I've tried to create a regex to achieve that but I don't know exactly how I am supposed to deal with that. Here is the code I made:

`$output =  preg_replace('[0-9ABCDEF]{5}[0-9ABCDEF]{5}[0-9ABCDEF]{5}[0-9ABCDEF]{5}', '$1-$2-$3-$4', $input);`

It's pretty basic but I can't make it works.

`$input` contains a raw string; For example `A47D2F771AC412BADC4F` (20 chars long).

Thanks in advance for your precious help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the groups.

```
 preg_replace('([0-9A-F]{5})([0-9A-F]{5})([0-9A-F]{5})([0-9A-F]{5})', ...
#              ^           ^^           ^^           ^^           ^
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this non regex approach and save yourself a headache:

```
$pieces = str_split( $input, 5 );

$formatted_input = implode("-", $pieces);
```

Comment: I think this is faster too